# No-code or little-code website

Tags: web, drag-and-drop, wysiwyg

What is a (free) technology which requires the least amount of code for creating a website with the following requirements:

- Sign-up/login
- Form for adding your personal info. which gets databased
- Each person can view and edit their own info
- Admin can view and edit any
- The form needs to be easily customizable and extensible (by the website's owner, not during run-time)

Is there a beginner tutorial for such a thing?

(For me, this question is about a friend who wants me to do this, but I want him to do it himself so I don't have to get roped into maintenance. I also want to keep it more general for the sake of Stack Overflow and future readers.)

**Edit**: I thought I remembered some ASP.NET tutorials that were mostly drag/drop or things where it was all but made for you from the database schema (which can be made with SSMS's GUI) but I can't seem to find them now.

Responding to posts below requesting specifics: this site will be for potential clients to sign-up and enter their company's info and fill out a form about their advertising needs.

I thought about putting this on SU instead, but since there was likely going to be some coding involved (I assumed no-code was an unreachable goal) SO seemed more appropriate.

Comment: No-code solutions are available, so this question seems more suitable for SU.

Comment: there is always sharepoint lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend can consider a framework like [drupal](http://drupal.org/). It has a bit of a learning code but, you can create a website with everything you ask for without code. You may want to modify it to change the look but there are themes for that.

Also, some hosts like godaddy.com have this installed and you do not have to worry about the complex installation procedures. Just start modifying the content of the site, select a built in template and go...

Answer (score 1):

PhpBB? I think you need to specify what the website is going to be used for before you can get better/more specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

... have a look at Drupal or Joomla, expect a learning curve nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Is this friend a programmer as well? If so, I'd suggest building such a site using a PHP framework. Deploying an existing forum/wiki is also an option of course, but will probably have much more features than you describe. But if s/he's not a programmer, I don't see how s/he will be able to develop a site like that in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a CMS like wordpress, drupal and co. ?